# String vs [String] in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm wondering what the difference is when declaring variables as such...

```
Dim something as String = Nothing
```

and

```
Dim something as [String] = String.Empty
```

Specifically the difference between String and [String].

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: VBA in the title, VB.NET tag?  dont do the second; it is like naming your kid "child"

Comment: Plutonix - Sorry about that it was a slip of the keyboard.

Comment: definitely vb.net, not vba, as vba doesn't have string.empty.

Comment: Also, the biggest difference in those code samples is that String.Empty is completely different from `Nothing`. Nothing is a null reference. String.Empty is a reference to a non-null string with a length of 0.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn `Nothing` is not a null reference, this is a default value of type. For reference types `Nothing` = `null`. But `Dim myint As Int32 = Nothing` will set value to 0. [From MSDN: Nothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference, apart from the fact that the first is `Nothing` and the second is an empty `string`.

You use the square brackets(`[...]`) around an [identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in VB.NET 
 to tell the compiler that it should ignore a [keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

It is often used on  `Enum`:

```
Dim colors = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(Colors))
```

since `Enum` is a keyword and a type. Without the brackets that wouldn't compile.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711644%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> Regular identifiers may not match keywords, but escaped identifiers
>   can. An escaped identifier is an identifier delimited by square
>   brackets.

Comment: Tim, why then does `Dim x As [String]` work and `Dim y As [Integer]` doesn't?

Comment: @roryap: try `Dim y As [Int32]`. I assume the compiler does not find `System.Int32` if you provide `Integer` with brackets. `Integer` is just  an alias for `System.Int32`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense.  I just couldn't wrap my head around why they were declaring things both ways in some code I'm revising.

Comment: So the problem is it doesn't work for type aliases then, just types.